# How to minimize function with two variables

Tags: r, optimization, minimum, minimize

I want to minimize function (log(37/1809)-log((1+a)/(1+a*exp(1)^(b*(99-79)))))^2 (**and find a and b values when value of function is minimum**) but i did not get the answer i know should be correct.

I write this code in R:

```
fixed=c(FALSE,FALSE)
params<- fixed
funkcija_S1 <- function(p) {
  params[!fixed] <- p
  a <- params[1]
  b <- params[2]
  S1<-(log(37/1809)-log((1+a)/(1+a*exp(1)^(b*(99-79)))))^2
}
airb<-optim(c(a=0, b=1), funkcija_S1)
airb=airb[1]
airb<-as.numeric(unlist(airb))
a=airb[1]
b=airb[2]
```

The answer I get is a = 0.82813..... and b = 0.23351....
The answer i SHOULD get is a = 0.803228 and b = 0.234345.
Values of a and b are changing depending on what i write as primary a and b values in this line:

```
airb<-optim(c(a=0, b=1), funkcija_S1)
```

Is it possible not to specify the primary values in this line? Or maybe there is another way to minimize this equation?

Comment: Your objective function isn't returning a value - you need to add `return(S1)` - however even doing this I cannot replicate your results. I get `a = 4.704025e-07` and `b = 0.9219234`. You should use constrained optimization, because a has to be greater than -1. The objective function can be simplified `k = log(37/1809);
  return(k - log((1+a)/(1+a*exp(b * 20)))^2)`

Comment: @JamesCurran, *incorrect*. The last value in a function is its implicit return value, and in this case `S1` is invisibly returned. While having an explicit `return` value is declarative and is generally a good idea in many cases, in this case it is not a problem.

Comment: Having your objective function rely on variables (`params`, `fixed`) outside of its environment and arguments is a bad idea in general. It risks reproducibility and can make troubleshooting difficult at best. Especially in this example, those variables are doing absolutely nothing for you, suggesting either (a) you inherited this obj func from somebody else, or (b) there is more to your function than we see here (which is certainly fine).

Comment: I took this obj func from example I found in youtube because i did not know how to minimize function with two variables. @r2evans maybe you can help me to minimize this function **in any other way**?